# Community server library - issue deleting a user

Tags: vb.net, community-server

I have been asked to fix a Community Server forum where thousands of users were created via a script. All of their profile pages are SEOspam for prescription drugs, etc. The forum was not using email verification or admin approval for newly registered users. I turned on the latter for now, but captcha would be nice.

My problem is that it is very cumbersome to mass delete these accounts. I set up a .net grid (Telerik Radgrid actually) so that I could mass select users and click delete. However the following code does not seem to be working (mind the VB nubbery):

```
Protected Sub rgUsers_NeedDataSource(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs) Handles rgUsers.NeedDataSource
    rgUsers.DataSource = Users.GetUsers().Users()
End Sub

Protected Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    For Each item As GridDataItem In rgUsers.SelectedItems
        Dim selectedUserID As Integer = item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues(item.ItemIndex)("UserID")
        Dim userToDelete As CommunityServer.Components.User = Users.GetUser(selectedUserID, False) ' User is definitely populated. '
        Dim username As String = userToDelete.Username
        Dim deleteStatus As DeleteUserStatus = Users.DeleteUser(User)
        Trace.Write(String.Format("Delete result for user {0}: {1}", username, deleteStatus.ToString)) ' Returns enum value 3 (Success.) '
    Next
    rgUsers.Rebind()
End Sub
```

The UserDeleteStatus result returns 'Success', however the user is not actually deleted. Am i using the correct delete function? Any help is greatly appreciated, as this is sort of time sensitive (the client is not in the market for penis enlargment pills.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the UserDeleteStatus was actually returning 'AuthenticationRequired'